# How to display nested Json data in different row in listview page in sencha touch-2.4.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

My output in view is like below

```
    Campaigns,Quotes,PurchaseOrder,SalesOrder,Calendar,Leads,Accounts
```

But I want line by line like below

```
      Campaigns 
      Quotes
      PurchaseOrder
      SalesOrder
      Calendar
      Leads
      Accounts
```

My JSON file

```
{"success":true,
"result":
{"types":   
["Campaigns","Quotes","PurchaseOrder",
"SalesOrder","Calendar","Leads","Accounts]      
}
}
```

My Model

```
fields: [
{name: 'success', type: 'boolean'},
{name: 'types', type:'auto', mapping:'result.types'}

],
```

My Itemtpl

```
itemTpl: '<tpl>{types}</tpl>',
```

My Store
    Ext.define('app1.store.mainmenustore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:[ 'Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage','Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'],
    config:
    {
     model : 'app1.model.mainmenumodel',

```
proxy:{
type:'ajax',
url:'http://192.168.50.118/crm/webservice.php?  
sessionName=sessionId&operation=listtypes',


reader:{
type:'json'

},
extraParams:{

sessionName: sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid')

},
});
```

Comment: Plz help to solve my problem because if I have list like above then I can proceed further

Comment: I think you may have a problem with your store and how you are loading the data. Can you post your store config code

Comment: I had sent my store . please let me know if I need any changes..

Comment: @mindparse can you check the comment I gave now

Comment: You should change it to the correct structure server side, can you do this? Also don't add comments as answers like you have just done, just use the 'add a comment' options

Comment: Is it possible to change structure sever side   ??Because I never did it before and I am new to sencha touch

Comment: It sounds to me then that you are not in control of the server side generated data, can you speak to the people who do this for you and show them this structure I have suggested?

Comment: @mindparse I dont have sever side rights so Is it possible client side?

Comment: Please let me know is it possible to do in client side or not. I am trying but not happening displaying in different row.

Comment: Problem with your json data, change it to key value pair, then map key to the model field name

Comment: The only other way I can think is that you load your data with an Ajax request and then in the success handler perform a string.split() on the data and then create new models in your store from each value. But this is a bit of a hack, can you not speak to the server side guys?

Comment: @mindparse Thanks a lot for your help because I was trying to solve this problem for 3 days but you told you can edit the structure of JSON file server side. Yes server side guy is working on that.

Comment: notice the tick and up arrows you can use on answers posted here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way your data is being returned in that json

["Campaigns","Quotes","PurchaseOrder",
"SalesOrder","Calendar","Leads","Accounts"]

It's just a flat single record which is why it appears as one line of strings in your view. Each string value needs to be wrapped in its own array or object.

So either an array of arrays:

```
[["Campaigns"],["Quotes"],["PurchaseOrder"]...]
```

Or as proper JSON encoded objects with named properties

```
[{type:"Campaigns"},{type:"Quotes"},{type:"PurchaseOrder"}...]
```

Your reader config should also have a rootProperty set to 'types' so it knows where in your response block the data begins.